# PFQueryTableView Custom cell Separator not showing

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle, pftableviewcell

In my `PFQueryTableViewController`, the custom `PFTableViewCell's` dont have any separators and i don't know why.

[image]

I didn't find anything when googeling.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    class CategoryTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.loadObjects()
    }


    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.parseClassName = "Category"

        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false


    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Mark - PFQueryTableViewController

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

        var query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName!)

        return query
    }

    // Mark: UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> (PFTableViewCell!) {
        var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! PFTableViewCell


        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        cell.textLabel?.text = object["name"] as? String

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you override the layoutSubviews() method in the PFTableViewCell class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Didn't find out what causes it yet, but here's a hack that I did which might help you too. In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** add this:

```
var separator = CALayer()
separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2).CGColor
separator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 1);
cell.layer.addSublayer(separator)
```

This will add a 1px layer that looks like a separator. You can play with the color, width of it.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Had to change the "100" for the hight of my cell. But you don't know why the separators don't show when using PFQueryTableViewController and PFTableViewCell?

Comment: No, as I said, I didn't manage to find out the cause of them not showing yet, unfortunately. I'm glad my little hack worked for you too!

Answer (score 6):

Override the `objectsDidLoad:` method with this and the UI should go back to normal:

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is quite old, but when I removed the `self.loadObjects()` from my `viewWillAppear` method the tableview separators came back. Not sure if this is a parse bug or not but I thought I would just point that out.